# How to compile a java binary with reflection security disabled?

Tags: java, security, reflection, illegalaccessexception

I'd like to disable reflective security both during the compilation, and running of my application. This means that essentially `java.lang.IllegalAccessError` will never be thrown. It also means that all reflective accesses to all types and all fields are allowed, and none are denied. Here, we can assume the entire project is compiled from source.

How does one accomplish this?

For this question, we can assume that we're using java 19

Comment: you would need to add `--add-opens` with the correct module and package at runtime...

Comment: woah, that's a neat flag. I'm reading the docs now..

Comment: Alternatively, you can change the `module-info.java` of the module to access and open the relevant packages. This approach should be preferred if possible.

Comment: And if your application and 3rd-party components depend on accessing the internals of the JDK itself ... you should probably change that.  'Cos it will get harder and harder with newer Java versions.